# .onion links not working at all

Tags: error, connection

Ive not used tor a great deal but never had any problems searching and finding .onion sites. now when i search any .onion even duckduckgo i get the firefox error page unable to connect etc etc internet connection has not changed and neither have my security software. already uninstalled and reinstalled tor browser.

Any help?

please thanks

Answer (score 0):

Onion services come and go quickly. It is no surprise that many of the ones that you might use are not functional. If you want to test your connection, a couple of ones that you can try are: [facebook](https://facebookcorewwwi.onion) and the [tor project](http://expyuzz4wqqyqhjn.onion).

Reddit's [r/onions](https://www.reddit.com/r/onions/) has a large collection of onion services that you can try but what site is up today may not be up tomorrow. That's because many people run onion services off of their own computers.